# Understanding preemptive multitasking with locks and the Python GIL?

Tags: python, locking, multitasking, gil

I'm reading through [Grok The GIL](https://opensource.com/article/17/4/grok-gil) and it has the following statement in the discussion about locking.

> So long as no thread holds a lock while it sleeps, does I/O, or some other GIL-dropping operation, you should use the coarsest, simplest locks possible. Other threads couldn't have run in parallel anyway.

It comes just after a discussion about preemptive multitasking. What prevents the preemptive dropping of the GIL from happening while you have a lock? Or is that not what this statement is referring to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked the author of the piece and it comes down to the difference between dropping the GIL because you are waiting on an external operation vs an internal preemtion: https://opensource.com/article/17/4/grok-gil#comment-136186

> Hi! Nothing prevents a thread from preemptively dropping the GIL while
> it holds a lock. Let's call that Thread A, and let's say there's also
> a Thread B. If Thread A holds a lock and gets preempted, then maybe
> Thread B could run instead of Thread A.
>
> If Thread B is waiting for the lock that Thread A is holding, then Thread B is *not* waiting for the GIL. In that case Thread A reacquires the GIL immediately after dropping it, and Thread A continues.
>
> If Thread B is not waiting for
> the lock that Thread A is holding, then Thread B might acquire the GIL
> and run.
>
> My point about coarse locks, however, is this: no two threads
> can ever execute Python in parallel, because of the GIL. So using
> fine-grained locks doesn't improve throughput. This is in contrast to
> a language like Java or C, where fine-grained locks allow greater
> parallelism, and therefore greater throughput.

I still needed some clarification, and he did confirm this:

> If I'm understanding you correctly, the intent of the statement I referenced was to avoid using locks around external operations, where you could then block multiple threads, if they all depended on that lock.
>
> For the preemptive example, Thread A isn't blocked by anything externally, so the processing just goes back and forth similar to cooperative multitasking.